# Named Begin errors in Logwatch

Tags: linux, centos, dedicated-server

We have a dedicated server with Fasthosts and are getting the following information via Logwatch.

We're trying to work out the 'Named Begin' section as on a daily basis there is hundreds of unmatched entries.

What is actually happening here and how do we stop it from happening?

Below is a truncated dsample from our report...

```
 ################### Logwatch 7.3 (03/24/06) #################### 
        Processing Initiated: Thu May 19 04:02:04 2011
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2011-May-18 )
                              Period is day.
      Detail Level of Output: 0
              Type of Output: unformatted
  ################################################################## 

 --------------------- Cron Begin ------------------------ 

 MAIL sending errors 32 Time(s)

 ---------------------- Cron End ------------------------- 


 --------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------ 


 Requests with error response codes
    404 Not Found
       /admin/Y-ivrrecording.php?php=info&ip=uname: 2 Time(s)
       /manager/html: 1 Time(s)

 ---------------------- httpd End ------------------------- 


 --------------------- Named Begin ------------------------ 


 **Unmatched Entries**
    client 174.129.147.140 query (cache) 'eboxresearch.com/A/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.147.140 query (cache) 'eboxsurvey.com/A/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.147.140 query (cache) 'ns0.eboxresearch.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.147.140 query (cache) 'ns0.eboxsurvey.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.147.140 query (cache) 'ns1.eboxresearch.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.147.140 query (cache) 'ns1.eboxsurvey.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.154.135 query (cache) 'eboxresearch.com/A/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.154.135 query (cache) 'eboxsurvey.com/A/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.154.135 query (cache) 'ns0.eboxresearch.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.154.135 query (cache) 'ns0.eboxsurvey.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.154.135 query (cache) 'ns1.eboxresearch.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 174.129.154.135 query (cache) 'ns1.eboxsurvey.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 184.105.224.2 query (cache) 'eboxsurvey.com/AAAA/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
    client 184.72.135.119 query (cache) 'eboxresearch.com/A/IN' denied: 1 Time(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No big worry here: People are querying your DNS server for your IPV6 address or a default A record. Obviously you don't have either one.

Comment: the eboxresearch address that is coming up in the report isn't our own so is this something that has been set up by the owners of that domain and wrongly pointed towards our server?

Comment: eboxsearch.com and exboxsurvey.com NS glue records point to 77.68.54.8 and 77.68.54.15. If these IPs are yours then you are right.

Comment: Thanks, have dropped an email to the owners of the domain to ask for them to have a look at their nameserver.